# Preventing to Bash script from running in parallel or overlap using cron

Tags: linux, bash, unix, cron

If i have the following entries in my cron table:

```
00 03 * * * /java_prog1.sh 
00 5 * * * /java_prog2.sh
```

The first job usually takes around 30 minutes to complete. The second job takes about 10 minutes. There are some exceptional situations where the first job takes more than two hours.

Is there a way i can configure the two jobs so that the second job does not start if the first one is still running?

I have seen several examples using tools like `flock` but i think flock does not apply here as i am not trying to prevent the same job running at the same time. I am trying to prevent another job to start if the previous one is still running.

Comment: Make your first cron job emit the PID somewhere on disk when it starts and clean it up when it's done.  That would make way for second to determine the status of the first.

Comment: Will the PID be the same for the first job every time it runs? I thought the PID is different on every execution.

Comment: I mentioned `emit the PID on disk` -- it implied write it to a file with a known name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just putting some flesh on top of the suggestions already there in the comments.

Put in the beginning of `java_prog1.sh`:

```
[ -f /var/run/java_prog1.sh.pid ] && exit
echo "$$" > /var/run/java_prog1.sh.pid

... everything else our script does ...

rm -f /var/run/java_prog1.sh.pid
```

Then in the beginning of `java_prog2.sh`:

```
[ -f /var/run/java_prog1.sh.pid ] && exit

... the rest of your java_prog2.sh ...
```

Or:

```
if [ -f /var/run/java_prog1.sh.pid ]; then
   kill -0 `cat /var/run/java_prog1.sh.pid` > /dev/null 2>&1 && exit
fi


... the rest of your java_prog2.sh ...
```

The first one will just exit immediately, if the a file (possibly and probably containing a PID from the first script) exists. The second one will exit only if the file exists and a process with a PID in in that file is in the process table (`kill -0` will return 0 in case it does).

As far as the actual scripting goes, you probably have to experiment a bit. This is just to give you a rought idea how it might go.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a way I can configure the two jobs so that the second job does not start if the first one is still running?

Since I can't comment, I will give you another example of what you could consider but of course @sami-laine solution is more elegant.

You can simply edit a config file like that:

## At startup:

```
echo 0 > file.config
```

## In your /java_prog1.sh:

```
echo 1 > file.config    # at the beginning of the script

do something ...      

echo 0 > file.config    # at the end of script 
                        #let the other script know that the job was finished
```

## In your /java_prog2.sh:

```
while [ `cat file.config` -eq 1 ] ; do sleep 5; done   # Wait whatever want
```

Answer (score 0):

The creation of directories is atomic, so you could add this in both scripts:

```
lock_dir=/tmp/name_of_lock_directory
if ! mkdir "$lock_dir"; then
    echo "Cannot run $0: lock directory $lock_dir exists" >&2
    exit 1
fi
cleanup () { rm -r "$lock_dir"; }
trap cleanup EXIT
# if you want, you can add the running pid to a file in the lock directory
echo $$ > "$lock_dir/pid"
```