# Cronjob in parallel time

Tags: linux, cron

I have 5 sh file which running the cronjob on same time every 5 min. In details, the queries will be output to the same table , namely X table. The issue is I did not get consistent data - missing data in X table. I found many reference and currently I am referring the sample from [Preventing to Bash script from running in parallel or overlap using cron](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22427859/preventing-to-bash-script-from-running-in-parallel-or-overlap-using-cron)

```
[ -f /var/run/java_prog1.sh.pid ] && exit 
echo "$$" > /var/run/java_prog1.sh.pid

       ... everything else our script does ...

 rm -f /var/run/java_prog1.sh.pid
```

. I just confuse , on the sample. Do I need to create the pid file or need to find the location the pid file ? . I did not found the pid file on the server.  I found the flock file /usr/share/man/man3p/flockfile.3p.gz. Can i just use you it ?  Currently one of the q is

```
#!/bin/sh
       echo "================================";
       date;d
       echo " kpi_inbound_error is RUNNING.";

       /var/PostgreSQL/9.4/bin/psql -h 10.0.x.x -d postgres -U postgres -w -f /home/samila/SQL_SMZ/kpi_inbound_error.sql

       date;
       echo " COMPLETED.--------------------";
```

Anyone can help me on the reference

Comment: Your question is unclear: you *do* create the PID file right there on the second file of your first code block, with the redirection.

Comment: Note by the way, that this does not prevent a race condition: a PID file could be created in the time between the first and second line of the code block above by another script, and will then be promptly be overwritten by the current script. You'll then have two (or more) processes running, but just one PID file listed. Create an (empty) directory can be a better way to create a file lock, since you can't overwrite that. Instead of checking for the existence of the directory, you just attempt to create, and the script will exit if that fails.

Comment: currently, i never yet create any file. I find the way to do it.

Comment: The current queries ( 5 queries ) which running through cron job  will be insert into one table. The worst case is  where few data is missing .  Currently,   I never yet create any PID  file and  I admit I dont know how to start it.