# bash : how to wait some time to avoid simultaneous run of a script?

Tags: bash, svn, concurrency, mutex, pbs

**My problem :**

Each night, my crontab launches several nightly tests on a supercomputer working with PBS under CentOS 6.5. When launched, the jobs wait in the queue. When the scheduler allow to run, my jobs start. It is quite common than the scheduler launch all the jobs exaclty at the same time (even if my crontab lauched them at separated moments).

I can't modify the main part of the job (but I can add things before). Each job starts with an update of a common SVN repository. But, when the jobs start simultaneously, I have an error due to concurrent updates on the same repository. I want to avoid that.

**What I expect :**

When launched by the scheduler, the job could wait some seconds before starting. A solution could be wait a random time before starting, but the risk to have the same random time grow fast with the number of tests I perform in parallel. If I reduce this risk by choosing a big random number, I have to wait too long (locking unused resources on the supercomputer).

I suppose it's possible to store the information of *"I will launch now, others have to wait for 1 minute"* for each job, in a multi-thread-safe manner, but I don't know how. What I imagine is a kind of mutex but inducing only a delay and not a lock waiting the end.

A solution without MPI is prefered.

Of course, I'm open to other solutions. Any help is welcome.

Comment: Maybe https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22427859/preventing-to-bash-script-from-running-in-parallel-or-overlap-using-cron is similar enough to help?

Answer (score 1):

Call your script from a wrapper that attempts to obtain an exclusive lock on a lock file first. For example

```
{
    flock -s 200
    # your script/code here
} 200> /var/lock/myscript
```

The name of the lock file doesn't really matter, as long as you have write permission to open it. When this wrapper runs, it will first attempt to get an exclusive lock on `/var/lock/myscript`. If another script already has the lock, it will block until the lock becomes available.

Note that there are no arbitrary wait times; each script will run as soon as possible, in the order in which they first attempt to obtain the lock. This means you can also start the jobs simultaneously; the operating system will manage the access to the lock and the ordering.

Comment: If I well understand, this will lock during all the script. I just want to lock during the first seconds of the script execution.

Comment: Hm. Maybe use the lock to serialize calls to `sleep 1`? Then each job nominally sleeps for 1 second, but has to wait for any previous jobs in line to complete *their* "1-second" sleep. In effect, the `n`th job sleeps for `n` seconds, without you having to manually assign different sleep times for each job.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution by using `GNU parallel`

It might seem a bit counter-intuitive at first to use this tool, but if you set the maximum number of jobs to run at a time to 1, it can simulate a job queue that runs multiple jobs in sequence without any overlaps.

You can observe the desired effect of this command by using this example

```
seq 1 5 | parallel -j1 -k 'echo {}; sleep 1'
```

`-j1` sets max jobs running at a time to 1 while `-k` preserves the order.

To apply this to your original problem, we can create say a file such that it contains a list of script files line by line. We can then pipe the content of that file to `parallel` to make multiple scripts run in sequence and in order.

```
cat file | parallel -j1 -k bash {}
```